# Does ntpdate work with SNTP?

Tags: debian, time-synchronization

I have an embedded system with Debian on ARM. I use `ntpdate` for time synchronization, but I am not sure whether it supports [SNTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#SNTP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sntp` (in the `ntp` debian package) does and it is the [intended replacement](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate) for ntpdate anyway.